# Facebook FQL stream object type

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-fql

Im trying to recreate a user's stream and present it the same way Fb does with a little picture representing persone/page/group and what was posted.  In order to objtain the picture, i have to query the user table for users, page table for pages, etc.  But looking at the [stream table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/), it doesnt look like it can tell me what exactly made the post, only its ID.  How do could i determine what table to query in order to get the objects picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the ID.  You can then use this url format for the picture:

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=small

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=normal

https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large

Just replace 4 with the ID you get. This works for pages, people, etc.

Comment: Ya, i thought that might be the only way to go.  It seems strange having to switch between the graph API and the FQL, thought i might be missing something.

Comment: The Graph API isn't feature complete just yet. We're working on migrating everything.